# Jenkins DSL: job with different job histories

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a parametrized job Dummy that works as expected. Then I have multiple jobs that call job A with a specific sets of parameters to run (job B for example).

Let's say job Dummy script is as follows:

```
def jobLabel = "dummy-" + env.JOB_BASE_NAME.replace('/', '-').replace(' ', '_') + "${PARAM}"
currentBuild.displayName = "Dummy ${PARAM}"

echo "Previous result: " + currentBuild.previousBuild.result

if (currentBuild.previousBuild.result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
    error("Build failed because of this and that..")
} else {
    echo "Dummy ${PARAM}!"
}
```

And job Test script as follows:

```
// in this array we'll place the jobs that we wish to run
def branches = [:]

def environments = [
    'US',
    'EU',
    'AU'
    ]

environments.each { env -> 
    branches["Dummy Tests " + env]= {
        def result = build job: 'Dummy', parameters: [
            string(name:'PARAM', value: env)
        ]

        echo "${result.getResult()}"
        if (result.getResult().equals("SUCCESS")) {
            echo "Success! " + env
        } else if (result.getResult().equals("FAILURE")) {
            echo "Failure! " + env
        }
    }
}
parallel branches
```

The previous job result is whatever ran last the previous time. I would like to somehow have the job history based on the parameter so I can detect when a specific job combination switches from failure to success and vice versa for notification purposes. I guess you could iterate the history for that but sounds too complicated for something that hopefully is common requirement. Any hints or ideas?